# Epsilon-Delta proof for Multivariate Limit in Polar Coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to construct an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof for the following limit, $$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)}\frac{4xy}{x^2 + y^2 + 2} = 0,$$
and I would like to see if my proof is sound having converted cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates.

My proof is as follows:

Let $x = r\cos\theta$, $y = r\sin\theta$ with $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, then
$$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)}\frac{4xy}{x^2 + y^2 + 2} = \lim_{r \rightarrow 0}\frac{4r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}{r^2+2}$$.

We note that $\forall\theta\in\mathbb{R}, 0 \leq|\cos\theta\sin\theta| < 1$.

Now, suppose that $0 < |r| < \delta$, for $\delta > 0$. We take $\delta < \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$, with $\varepsilon > 0$, then $0 < |r| < \delta < \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$.
$$
\begin{align*}
  \left|\frac{4r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}{r^2+2} - 0\right| &< \left|\frac{4r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}{r^2}\right|\\ &= 4|\cos\theta\sin\theta| \\
&<4|r||\cos\theta\sin\theta|\\
&<4|r| \\
&<4 \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{4} \\
&= \varepsilon
\end{align*}$$

Thus for $0<|r|<\delta$, we have $\left|\frac{4r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}{r^2+2}\right| < \varepsilon$. Hence, we conclude that
$$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)}\frac{4xy}{x^2 + y^2 + 2} = \lim_{r \rightarrow 0}\frac{4r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}{r^2+2}$$
exists and is equal to $0$.

Anyways, any feedback of how I could improve the proof (if it is correct) or correct anything would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, you say $4|\cos \theta \sin \theta| < 4|r||\cos \theta \sin \theta|$ without justification.  In fact, it just isn't true as $r< 1$ inside the neighborhood.  Instead, use $|r^2+ 2|>2$

Comment: @user317176 Oh I see, I hadn't actually considered $r < 1$, I must've just put it down without really thinking about it. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is wrong, because you made an $|r|$ appear out of thin air. Without it,  your expression does not go to zero.

Using polar coordinates here is overkill. What you should note is that the denominator is away from zero, so it is irrelevant (and the right bound to use was $2$ and not $r^2$). Then you can do the following:
$$
\Big|\frac{4xy}{x^2+y^2+2}\Big|\leq\frac{4|xy|}{2}=2|xy|\leq x^2+y^2. 
$$
Now you can take $\delta=\varepsilon^{1/2}$.

Comment: You mean $\delta^2 = \epsilon$ or use the square of the Euclidean metric and then it is just $\delta = \epsilon$

Comment: Thanks for noticing! Edited.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks very much, I had thought I could essentially introduce $|r|$ by multiplying it in, I thought surely that it would be bigger but had forgotten the case where $|r| < 1$ (which it is). I didn't notice that bound for the denominator before, thanks for pointing that out. Just wondering on where the idea that $2|xy| \leq x^2 + y^2$ comes from, I can't quite derive it myself and I'm wondering how it would be derived. Thanks again

Comment: It is derived from $(a-b)^2\ge0$ @Ammardian

Comment: @Ammardian: as Tim said, it's $(|x|-|y|)^2\geq0$. It's also a version of Young's inequality, but the direct approach is much easier.

Comment: @Tim Oh, I had thought about that, but wasn't really sure how the absolute value signs came into play. I certainly get the fact that $(a - b)^2 \geq 0 \implies 2ab \leq a^2 + b^2$ but yeah, just wasn't quite sure about where the absolute value signs came in.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Ahh I see, that more general version definitely helps my understanding there, it makes a lot of sense that way, introduces the absolute value signs because I wasn't sure where they came in.